# Subquery returned more than 1 value even with IN operator

Tags: sql, sql-server

My query is quite big but for understanding purpose I paste here

```
SELECT    DISTINCT 
                  ISNULL(CD.InteractionID,'')       AS  InteractionID
                , ISNULL(CD.CaseID,'')                  AS CaseID
                , ISNULL(CD.AnalysisMonth,'')  + '-' + CAST( AnalysisYear AS VARCHAR(10)) AS MonYr
                , ISNULL(ServiceType,'')            AS ServiceType
                , ISNULL(ServiceSubType,'')         AS ServiceSubType  
                , ISNULL(SM.SourceName,'')          AS SourceName
                , ISNULL(UserComment,'')            AS UserComment
                , ISNULL(Final,'')                  AS Final
                , ISNULL(SYSM.SystemName,'')        AS SystemName
                , ISNULL(SSM.SubSystem,'')          AS SubSystem
                , ISNULL(CM.CategoryDesc,'')        AS CategoryDesc
                , ISNULL(ITCM.ITCommentDesc,'')     AS ITCommentDesc
                , ISNULL(Casedetails,'')            AS Casedetails
                , ISNULL(TempRCA,'')                AS TempRCA
                , ISNULL(FinalRCA,'')               AS FinalRCA
                , ISNULL(SysOwnerComments  ,'')     AS SysOwnerComments 
             FROM     
                [IT_COMPLAINTS].[ITC_Casedetails]       CD      WITH (NOLOCK) 
            INNER JOIN  [IT_COMPLAINTS].ITC_SourceMaster        SM      WITH (NOLOCK) ON  CD.SourceID   =SM.SourceID    
            LEFT JOIN   [IT_COMPLAINTS].[ITC_SystemMaster]      SYSM    WITH (NOLOCK) ON  CD.SystemID   =SYSM.SystemID    
            LEFT JOIN   [IT_COMPLAINTS].[ITC_SubSystemMaster]   SSM     WITH (NOLOCK) ON  CD.SubSystemID=SSM.SubSystemID AND CD.SystemID=SSM.SystemID    
            LEFT JOIN   [IT_COMPLAINTS].[ITC_CategoryMaster]    CM      WITH (NOLOCK) ON  CD.CategoryID =CM.CategoryID    
            LEFT JOIN   [IT_COMPLAINTS].[ITC_ITCommentMaster]   ITCM    WITH (NOLOCK) ON  CD.ITCommentID=ITCM.ITCommentID   
            INNER JOIN  [IT_COMPLAINTS].[ITC_SystemUserMapping] MAP WITH (NOLOCK) ON SSM.SubSystemID = MAP.SubSystemID
           WHERE 
                (IsNull(@InteractionNo,'')=''   OR ISNULL(CD.InteractionID,'')=@InteractionNo) 
            AND (ISNULL(@Mon,'' )=''            OR ISNULL(CD.AnalysisMonth,'')=@Mon) 
            AND (IsNull(@Year,0)=0              OR ISNULL(CD.AnalysisYear,'')=@Year) 

--    
            AND CD.SystemID IN 
                 ( CASE WHEN @SystemID = 0 THEN 
                         (SELECT SystemID 
                          FROM IT_COMPLAINTS.ITC_SystemUserMapping 
                          WHERE UserID = @UserID AND IsActive = 1) 
                   ELSE @SystemID END)

            AND CD.SubSystemID IN 
                 (CASE WHEN @SystemID = 0 THEN 
                       (SELECT SubSystemID 
                        FROM IT_COMPLAINTS.ITC_SystemUserMapping 
                        WHERE UserID = @UserID AND IsActive = 1) 
                  WHEN @SystemID > 0 AND @SubSystemID = 0 THEN 
                       (SELECT SubSystemID 
                        FROM IT_COMPLAINTS.ITC_SystemUserMapping 
                        WHERE UserID = @UserID AND 
                              IsActive = 1 AND 
                              SystemID = @SystemID)
                  ELSE @SubSystemID END)
--
            AND (ISNULL(@CategoryID,'')=''      OR ISNULL(CD.CategoryID,'')=@CategoryID) 
            AND (ISNULL(@ITCommentID,0)=0       OR ISNULL(CD.ITCommentID,'')=@ITCommentID)
```

However when I run this , It gives me an error

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Problem is in following part

```
AND CD.SystemID IN 
    ( CASE WHEN @SystemID = 0 THEN 
      (SELECT SystemID 
       FROM IT_COMPLAINTS.ITC_SystemUserMapping 
       WHERE UserID = @UserID AND 
         IsActive = 1) ELSE @SystemID END) 
AND CD.SubSystemID IN 
          (CASE WHEN @SystemID = 0 THEN 
            (SELECT SubSystemID 
             FROM IT_COMPLAINTS.ITC_SystemUserMapping 
             WHERE UserID = @UserID AND 
               IsActive = 1) 
          WHEN @SystemID > 0 AND @SubSystemID = 0 THEN 
           (SELECT SubSystemID 
            FROM IT_COMPLAINTS.ITC_SystemUserMapping 
            WHERE UserID = @UserID AND 
              IsActive = 1 AND 
              SystemID = @SystemID)
          ELSE @SubSystemID END)
```

when I comment this, my query works, but whats the problem with `IN` `Subquery` and `Case` here?

Comment: I don't think you can use `CASE` inside `IN (...)`

Comment: You have multiple subqueries in that condition.  One of them is returning more than one value.

Comment: Replace that part WITH LEFT JOINs. ON x=y AND..

Comment: you might just need to add `distinct` or `group by` to encourage returning one row

Comment: Why all the NOLOCK hints here? Are you ok with inaccurate results in your query? http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/ You also have a LOT of nonSARGable predicates in your where clause here. You seem to have a number of columns that allow NULL but you have to constantly force it to an empty string. This kind of thing is going to kill your performance.

Comment: you should be able to narrow down the problem further by commenting out 2 of the 3 `SELECT` statements.  One or more of those is returning more than one value, which may be the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @zedfoxus commented, the problem is this part:

... THEN (SELECT SubSystemID FROM IT_COMPLAINTS.ITC_SystemUserMapping

Since if that returns more than 1 value, there is no place to put that value. You should replace this with something like this:

```
CD.SubSystemID IN (
    SELECT 
      SubSystemID 
    FROM 
      IT_COMPLAINTS.ITC_SystemUserMapping 
    WHERE 
      UserID = @UserID AND 
      IsActive = 1 AND 
      (
        @SystemID = 0 or 
        (SystemID = @SystemID and @SubSystemID = 0)
      ) 
    union all 
    select @SybSystemID where @SystemID > 0 and @SubSystemID > 0
    )
```

This might require small adjustments, but you should get the idea.

Instead of this, you might want to look into using "if exists" kind of structure. It's usually a lot simpler to write and performs better too.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you would return multiple values for `SubSystemID` without `AND SystemID = @SystemID` in the following `WHERE` clause:

```
        WHEN @SystemID = 0
            THEN (
                    SELECT SubSystemID
                    FROM IT_COMPLAINTS.ITC_SystemUserMapping
                    WHERE UserID = @UserID
                        AND IsActive = 1
                    )
```

Comment: And in this case it would be `AND SystemID = 0`

Answer (score 0):

instead of this:

```
            FROM     
                [IT_COMPLAINTS].[ITC_Casedetails]  CD  WITH (NOLOCK) 
...    
AND CD.SystemID IN 
    ( CASE WHEN @SystemID = 0 THEN 
      (SELECT SystemID 
       FROM IT_COMPLAINTS.ITC_SystemUserMapping 
       WHERE ...) ELSE @SystemID END) 
AND CD.SubSystemID IN 
          (CASE WHEN @SystemID = 0 THEN 
            (SELECT SubSystemID 
             FROM IT_COMPLAINTS.ITC_SystemUserMapping 
             WHERE ...) 
          WHEN @SystemID > 0 AND @SubSystemID = 0 THEN 
           (SELECT SubSystemID 
            FROM IT_COMPLAINTS.ITC_SystemUserMapping 
            WHERE ...)
          ELSE @SubSystemID END)
```

consider `left outer join`ing table `IT_COMPLAINTS.ITC_SystemUserMapping` on `CD.SystemID` and `CD.SubSystemID`

like:

```
FROM  [IT_COMPLAINTS].[ITC_Casedetails]  CD  WITH (NOLOCK) left outer join
      IT_COMPLAINTS.ITC_SystemUserMapping i on
         CD.SystemID = @SystemID or
         (@SystemID = 0 and 
          CD.SystemID = SystemID and UserID = @UserID AND IsActive = 1 ) and
         CD.SubSystemID = @SubSystemID or
         (CD.SubSystemID = SubSystemID and 
          UserID = @UserID AND IsActive = 1 and 
          (@SystemID = 0 or 
           @SystemID > 0 AND SystemID = @SystemID))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can identify users and system pairs that could be causing the problem with a query like this:

```
SELECT
    UserID, SystemID,
    count(*) as "Count",
    min(SubSystemID) as minSubSystemID, max(SubSystemID) as maxSubSystemID)
FROM IT_COMPLAINTS.ITC_SystemUserMapping 
WHERE IsActive = 1
GROUP BY UserID, SystemID
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

I agree with @JamesZ's answer. If you don't like the union and the query without a `from` clause, I think you can do it in a single query.

```
SELECT SubSystemID 
FROM IT_COMPLAINTS.ITC_SystemUserMapping 
WHERE
    UserID = @UserID AND IsActive = 1 AND 
    (
            @SystemID = 0
        or  SystemID = @SystemID and @SubSystemID = 0
        --  assumes that there's a row in this table with this SubSystemID
        or  SubSystemID = @SubSystemID
    )
```